# Function for mean and sem in Sweave/knitr implementation

Tags: r, function, latex, sweave, knitr

I am brainstorming to write a mean and sem function for Sweave/knitr use. And for my limited knowledge it look like this

```
m.se <- function (x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    if (na.rm) 
        x <- x[!is.na(x)]
    n <- length(x)
    if (n == 0) 
        return(c(mean = NA, sem = NA))
     xbar <- sum(x)/n
     se <- sqrt(sum((x - xbar)^2)/(n - 1))/sqrt(n)
     c(mean = xbar, sem = se)
     return(paste(xbar,"\\pm",se))
}
```

It really does some job and it give output like:

```
43.9303846153846 \pm 3.34823050767781
```

The problem is it does not respect `option()` that I define in main environment (setup chunk in knitr).
How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `format` function will do the trick:

```
R> 1.1111111
[1] 1.111
R> paste(1.1111111)
[1] "1.1111111"
R> paste(format(1.1111111))
[1] "1.111"
```

So in your case,

```
paste(format(xbar), "\\pm", format(se))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code for the mean and standard deviation is not optimal. As Dieter Menne mentioned, you can simply use the built-in `mean()` and `sd()` if you are not doing this for exercise purposes.

The `knitr` package has made a lot of efforts to better print numbers, and I recommend you to use these facilities instead of inventing your own formatting rules. See below for my solution (`\Sexpr{}` will respect `options('digits')`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<mean-sem>>=
options(digits = 3)
m.se <- function (x, ...) {
  n <- length(x)
  if (n == 0) return(c(mean = NA, sem = NA))
  se <- sd(x, ...)/sqrt(n)
  c(mean = mean(x, ...), sem = se)
}
res <- m.se(rnorm(100))
@

What you want is $\Sexpr{res['mean']} \pm \Sexpr{res['sem']}$.

\end{document}
```

More importantly, this is a portable solution -- if you want an HTML version, you simply write `<!--rinline res['mean']--> ± <!--rinline res['sem']-->`, and you do not have to redefine your R function.

Comment: Thanks Yihui, this is another solution. But when one writhes long and complex document, one must keep the coding part tidy, otherwise is is quiet confusing. But I did find solution, atleast it works for me. And code is `m.se <- function (x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  if (na.rm) 
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  n <- length(x)
  if (n == 0) 
    return(c(mean = NA, sem = NA))
  xbar <- sum(x)/n
  se <- sqrt(sum((x - xbar)^2)/(n - 1))/sqrt(n)
  c(mean = xbar, sem = se)
  return(paste(format(xbar),"$\\pm$",format(se)))
}` . @dieter-menne's code is more elegant but did not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Yihui: Both are valid approaches, but when you write  $\Sexpr{res['mean']} \pm \Sexpr{res['sem']}$ very often, having a shorthand that puts in the \pm into the Sexpr is helpful, so I tend to agree with Rafik. In old days with latex only, that was easy, but nowadays I try to make the print-classes aware of the latex/HTML processing context to output the correct separators.

Comment: @DieterMenne That makes sense. Another minor issue is I would rather define the S3 method on `format()` instead of `print()`.

Answer (score 1):

As @csgilliespie noted, the format statement will do the job, but this does not yet solve the problem that you probably want formatting to serve `option(digit=3)`. Best do this in a two-step approach, by separating numerics from view. See for example `print.lm` (without the ()).

```
m.se <- function (x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  if (na.rm) 
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  n <- length(x)
  if (n == 0) 
    return(c(mean = NA, sem = NA))
  xbar <- sum(x)/n
  se <- sqrt(sum((x - xbar)^2)/(n - 1))/sqrt(n)
  ret = c(mean = xbar, sem = se)
  class(ret) ="m.se"
  ret
}

print.m.se = function(x, digits = max(3, getOption("digits") - 3),...){
  print(paste(format(x["mean"],digits=digits), "//pm",format(x["sem"],digits=digits)))
  invisible(x)
}

m.se(rnorm(10))
```

Comment: This seems the right way to go. In majority of cases I use `option(digits=2)`, in that case I every time must change the code setting max value and -3. Originally, I would like the code to respect `.GlobalEnv` option digits. In that case I would write `digits=getOption("digits")`. And I can confirm that it really worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are using this function as an exercise in writing R code, it is fine. However, for serious work I recommend using the build in functions for variance which is better optimized against numeric problems.

Comment: Hi @dieter-menne, it is still me straggling with this piece of code.
When I do it in R it gives "mean \\pm sem" output as was disired. But when compiling with knitr in RStudio, it come out like "mean, sem" and no trace from \pm. How can I fix this code?

Comment: Use the so called Dalgaard-rule: If you believe you have been using the right number of backslashed, double these. Four backslashed might be right, I remember a case of 8...

Comment: The correct version of the Dalgaard-rule: http://markmail.org/message/5rry23dw5gxoapgf : The generic rule for backslashes is that you need twice as many as you thought.

Comment: This code `print.pval = function(pval) {
  threshold = 0.01
  return(ifelse(pval < threshold, paste("\\textit{p$<$}", sprintf("%.2f", threshold), sep=""),
                ifelse(pval > 0.1, paste("\\textit{p=}",round(pval, 2), sep=""),
                       paste("\\textit{p=}", round(pval, 2), sep=""))))
}` has no problem, for example, and I can not find difference? What is , @dieter-menne, in your opinion the difference.